# Why do upvote on questions fetch different reputation than upvote on answers?

Tags: discussion

An upvote on a question fetches +5. Whereas an upvote on an answer fetches +10. Why is this so? Isn't asking the right question important to get the right answer?

Comment: See ["Important Reputation Rule Changes"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) for a full explanation of this.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks. This is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site is about getting answers to questions, so it makes sense to award answers more.

It's much easier to ask a question about something you don't know the answer to than it is to have the answer to a question.

Finally - answering a question is providing direct help to someone, whereas asking for help is requesting someone give up their time for you.

The fact a question remains open and appropriate enough to get answers is basically its own reward. If someone chooses to take time to provide a solution then that is something more worthy of a reward than just being able to articulate a problem. Giving a reward for asking a question is really just a way of encouraging content to the site. But giving a reward for answers is a way of encouraging *quality, useful content* to the site.

Comment: "It is much easier to ask a question" .. I don't quite agree with that.. What Stack Exchange considers to be a good question is one that shows effort and good research. It is not easy to ask such a question.

Comment: But the answer to a question is stage two of the process. Stage 1: have a problem. Stage 2: solve the problem. It's harder to get to stage 2 than stage 1, therefore it deserves more reward.